# Why are my faces rounded

Tags: faces

i just cut the thing there out and made new faces in there. But why are they rounded?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Rounded faces]

Comment: You have a subdiv surface modifier with levels set to 3 on your object which will produce that effect. Either turn off the modifier or slightly inset the faces that you want to have sharp corners.

Comment: If you use the inset method you'll need to delete the edge split modifier too.